# Why does new PDO throws an error on the following?

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following configuration.

```
private $host = '127.0.0.1';
    private $db = 'loginexample';
    private $dbusername = 'root';
    private $dbpass = 'root';

$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};charset=utf8", $dbusername, $dbpass);
```

**But if i do this**

```
$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname=loginexample;charset=utf8", root, root);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables are private class properties, so you need to be using `$this` on all of them:

```
private $host = '127.0.0.1';
private $db = 'loginexample';
private $dbusername = 'root';
private $dbpass = 'root';

$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->db};charset=utf8", $this->dbusername, $this->dbpass);
```

When you insert the literal values, it connects (hope your password isn't `root`). And since `$host` is not defined (and therefore `NULL`, it defaults to the driver's default value, which is `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`).

It seems like you may not have error_reporting enabled, since you would be seeing notices for undefined variables.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: That would be a runtime error, not a PDO error

Comment: @ColeJohnson Why? It's a double quoted string. (Also the OP doesn't really say what the error is)

Comment: @Michael oh nvm (15 characters)